# Download Large File with PHP readfile(); Downloading is stopping around 890mb

Tags: php, header, readfile

I write some small script and it is working ok! however when i try download large file such a more than 1GB Download is stopping around ~880MB

Am i doing something wrong?  or is there any better solution for download big file with PHP

This is my code

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '5000M');

//This File is 4GB size
$url = 'example.com/files/file_name.zip';

$headers = get_headers($url, TRUE); //collectind header information from file Url

$filesize = $headers['Content-Length']; //File size

while (ob_get_level()) ob_end_clean();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: filename=' . basename($url));
header('Content-length: ' . $filesize);
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked");
ob_flush();
flush();
readfile($url);
exit;
```

Comment: Script looks fine. Check your server logs.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you're hitting a memory limit error. Normally `readfile` avoids using much memory, but depending on your settings it can consume RAM in the process. Check your error logs to confirm that you're seeing a memory allocation error, and if you are seeing it, try getting rid of the `while` and `ob_flush` and `flush` and just add something like this after the headers:

```
if (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}

readfile($url);
```

Also, don't pump your memory limit up to 5GB... if this is working correctly you shouldn't require hardly any memory.

If that's not it, can you confirm that you're serving a remotely hosted ZIP file (i.e. you don't have direct access to the ZIP file on the current server)?

Comment: Hello @ben_d  

Thanks for your response!  

Zip and .iso files are in my own server, I want to protect my files path.
Is there any different solutions than readfile() function.  

I made a plenty search all over the internet can`t find any good solutions.  

But when i run script from main server which is files are hosted, downloading is stopping around 550mb~890mb.  

If I host script different than my own server, script is working perfect.

Comment: If it's on your own server, I think that you might want to change this to stream directly from the file source rather than the URL. So change to:

`$url = '/local/path/file_name.zip';

Get rid of the `get_headers` call, and instead just set:

`$filesize=filesize($url);`

Then you're streaming from a local source rather than having the server talk to itself over HTTP

Comment: Ben, Can you provide optimal code to hide original file path and serving the download via php file (Especially not to hog on server) really i was so much curious about this, whether to serve file direct link or through php.